Does galvanic corrosion cease after dissimilar metals are separated?
I have aluminum in contact with steel in ambient conditions (exposed to atmosphere, no contact with water or electrolytes). The steel has started rusting, and the aluminum has started corroding, I assume due to galvanic corrosion.
If I remove the steel from the aluminum, will the aluminum continue corroding?

Since they are both corroding it is unlikely the Al is sacrificially protecting the steel. Paint sounds like a better protection. Examine the ambient conditions more thoroughly.

@jimchmst The aluminum was painted, the corrosion started bubbling up under the paint after which point the paint started to chip. At least anecdotally this is quite common in the bike world with dissimilar metals, and it does not happen with metals of the same type.

You have everything happening at once altho the Al is reacting directly not only sacrificially to protect Al a good anodization followed by impervious paint is necessary Insulation from more noble metals is necessary. I have found in studies of Al corrosion traces of Cu, Mn and other metals in the Al are sufficient to be internal cathodes facilitating corrosion if the protection is breached.

If iron (steel) and aluminum are in complete contact, the aluminum acts as a sacrificial anode and protects the iron. In fact, aluminized steel is made to make the underlying steel more rust resistant, just as galvanizing protects iron nails and buckets.
In the process of protecting the steel, the aluminum (or zinc) is damaged, forming powdery deposits on the protected metal.
Of course, if you value the aluminum part, it's not good practice to have it in direct contact with iron. A steel bolt in direct contact with aluminum brake calipers will speed their corrosion.
So why did the iron part rust? Likely, something abraded the paint or other protective covering. But don't blame the aluminum -- it gave all, sacrificing itself to try to save that steel!
